# How to efficiently reorder rows based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 20, 20],
                   'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']})

    col_1   col_2
0   10      a
1   20      b
2   10      c
3   20      d
4   10      e
5   10      f
6   20      g
7   20      h
```

I don't want consecutive rows with col_1 = 10, instead a row below a repeating 10 should jump up by one (in this case, index 6 should become index 5 and vice versa), so the order is always 10, 20, 10, 20...

My current solution:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['col_1'] == 10 and df.iloc[idx + 1]['col_1'] != 20:
        df = df.rename({idx + 1:idx + 2, idx + 2: idx + 1})

df = df.sort_index()
df
```

gives me:

```
    col_1   col_2
0   10      a
1   20      b
2   10      c
3   20      d
4   10      e
5   20      g
6   10      f
7   20      h
```

which is what I want but it is very slow (2.34s for a dataframe with just over 8000 rows).
Is there a way to avoid loop here?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom `key` in [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df.sort_values(by='col_1', kind='stable', key=lambda s: df.groupby(s).cumcount())
```

Output:

```
   col_1 col_2
0     10     a
1     20     b
2     10     c
3     20     d
4     10     e
6     20     g
5     10     f
7     20     h
```

Comment: I believe this doesn't work if the first col_1 value is 20. To address this, you could add `df.sort_values('col_1')` before sorting with the custom `key`.

Comment: @BenjaminZiepert yes, then you can do this as the second sort is stable

Comment: @BenjaminZiepert First value will always be 10, but thanks for the heads up!