# How to sort a dataframe's column of values so that no identical elements are contiguous/adjacent

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

If I have A, A, B, B, B, C, E and want to sort the values so that no identical elements are contiguous, then the sort may result in: A, B, A, B, C, B, E. There may be other combinations of sort for this very set of data.

I would like to sort the item column of the dataframe above mentioned way and want to know the technical/formal name for this sorting method. Googling did not help much.

The closest approach I can think of is conditional count of item values with a cumulative window and then sort by that conditional count column but coding that appears very challenging. Any insights will be appreciated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'item':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'E'],
    'person':[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
})

df.sort_values('item', kind='heapsort') # <<< Of course, heapsort does not solve the purpose
```

Comment: `quicksort` is default method if that is your question

Answer (score 3):

> The closest approach I can think of is conditional count of item values with a cumulative window and then sort by that conditional count column but coding that appears very challenging.

You can use something like:

```
>>> (df.assign(count=df.groupby('item').cumcount())
       .sort_values(['count', 'item'])
       .drop(columns='count')

  item  person
0    A       1
3    B       2
5    C       2
6    E       1
1    A       1
4    B       2
2    A       2
```

**Update**

I found another answer which is more performant and elegant from [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74862977/15239951)

```
>>> df.sort_values(by='item', kind='stable', key=lambda s: df.groupby(s).cumcount())

  item  person
0    A       1
3    B       2
5    C       2
6    E       1
1    A       1
4    B       2
2    A       2
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know the technical name of this sort method?

Comment: There is no particular name for that. It's just a sort based on condition. Check the other answer.